# How to pass variable inside .kv file

Tags: python, variables, widget, kivy, kivy-language

i want to pass textinput.text as an argument in root.myfunc(textinput.text)
so that function name myfunc() in .py file get this argument and it print random list according to that argument

Here is my .py file:

```
import kivy
import random
kivy.require('1.11.1')
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App

class myclass(Widget):
    a=10
    def my_func(self):
        randomlist=[]
        for i in range(5):
            num=random.randint(1,20)
            randomlist.append(num)

        print(randomlist)




class Myapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return myclass()

Myapp().run()
```

Here is my .kv file:

```
 Button:
        id:b1
        text:"Display"
        size:(120,50)
        size_hint:(.5,.5)
        pos:(130,290)
        on_release: root.my_func()
    TextInput:
        id:t1
        size:(170,50)
        pos:(130,365)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the text input by its ID, and then you can pass its text attribute as an argument to your function.

#### kv:

```
<myclass>
    Button:
        id:b1
        text:"Display"
        size:(120,50)
        size_hint:(.5,.5)
        pos:(130,290)
        on_release: root.my_func(t1.text)

    TextInput:
        id:t1
        size:(170,50)
        pos:(130,365)
```

#### And the python function:

```py
    def my_func(self, text):
        randomlist=[]
        for i in range(5):
            num=random.randint(1,20)
            randomlist.append(num)

        print(text)
        print(randomlist)
```